# How to skip or remove some file at run time from uploading list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, node.js, jquery-file-upload

I'm using `blueimp plugin` https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/API

I need to remove some files, during run time, from the **queue**.

When status `code 17` **(File Already Exits)** from the server, then that particular file should be removed.

This is what I have tried so far to no success.

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: 'url.php',
    maxChunkSize: 65536, // 120 KB,
    maxRetries: 10,
    dataType: 'json',
    multipart: false,
    sequentialUploads: true,
    add:function(){........},
    done:function(){........}
}).on('fileuploadchunkdone', function (e, data) {
    if(data.result.status == 17){
        var currentFileObject = data.files[0];
        var index = data.originalFiles.indexOf(currentFileObject); // find index in originalFiles
        data.originalFiles.splice(0,index);
        //data.files.length = 0; // if i uncomment this line some error will come, like undefined fileName
        data.submit();
    }
});
```

I am **removing** the file by `finding` in  `data.originalFiles`

**NOTE:**(**please note**) i'm not using any `ui provided by plugin (cancel, update, crop image, thumbnail)` etc

**created fiddle for experimenting**:http://jsfiddle.net/ChJ9B/219/

Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks  in advance  !!!!

Comment: Define "not working".  What does it do?  The file stays in the list?  Error message?

Comment: @Nic3500, im still sending that file chunk to `server` even though i **removed** it from `data.originalFiles` array  (when i got status code 17)

Comment: specifically i don't want to send the file which i have removed as a successive chunk

Comment: I have no way of testing this right now, but I recon you have multiple ways of solving this problem. The easiest is probably by sending an error http code back when you don't want upload to continue (e.g. a 412 Precondition Failed). Currently you are sending a success http code, which signals the jquery plugin to continue uploading.

Comment: @Sumurai8, i don't want to `abort` whole `uploading process`, just i want to skip the `file` which is already exists in **backend** **(if status code is 17 then skip)**

Comment: @EaB If nothing else you can leave this work to the server. I understand you want to save traffic, but maybe there are limitations when it comes to file upload..

Comment: @EaB. Can you make a fiddle of this

Comment: @SudharshanNair, i have created a fiddle can you please check http://jsfiddle.net/ChJ9B/219/

Comment: You are using classic http-request for networking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.abort()` method to cancel the uploading of the files.

In your case, you can save all the fileupload request to an object and then abort the specific one.

```
filesList.forEach(function(elm) {
    jqXHR[elm.name] =  $('#fileupload').fileupload('send', {files: elm});// you should save some id or timestamp
});
```

and then in the callback to the `fileuploadchuckdone` event, you can look for the name of the file and then abort from the `jqXHR` object.

```
function (e, data) {
    if(data.result.status == 17){
        var currentFileName = data.files[0].name; // read the name somehow?
        jqXHRMap[currentFileName].abort();
    }
});
```

P.S. I haven't run the code, just sharing the idea.

Comment: your answer seems to be pretty good, i tried it out , don't know what i have missed(code placement wise or else).  **i have created a fiddle can you please try the above solution.    Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/ChJ9B/219/**

Comment: Due to unavailability of time, I couldn't add the exact code but I have hardcoded it and it works. Please have a look. http://jsfiddle.net/0zb84xy3/

Comment: yes  i have tried your code but for me it did not work, if you open your **console -> Network section in Headers Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=""**    `filename` is sending always even though it is intended for  skip . here is the screen https://ibb.co/ianPXJ

Comment: i have tried the your code with harcoded value matching my original file name, but did not work? please help me before my bounty expires

Comment: The filename will be sent as this is how the MIME requests work. But the network request should be in cancelled state once you click on the cancel button.
 To test it, you should apply the network throttling from the developer tools and then try to hit the cancel button (meanwhile the request is in progress). It should cancel the network request and will stop uploading for that file.
Img: https://ibb.co/cNe1CJ

Comment: Though, I have removed the hardcoded data from the code and it works now as a charm. http://jsfiddle.net/zokc04u5/1/
You should add multiple files and throttle the network connection to test it. 
Just another screenshot: https://ibb.co/ieq8Bd
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You should just call `data.abort();` It should do the work.

Or you can also call `data.context.remove()`

Comment: `data.context.remove()` is not working.    AND  `data.abort()` is aborting whole upload process. just i want to skip those files, for which i got `status code 17`

**thanks alot for posting your valuable solution!!!**

Comment: can you debug is there is any error while running - data.context.remove() ?  It should work as per the code of the plugin. You can run this only in your if condition.